# Download Image from Url iOS 10 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

This is the function i used before to download image from url. I was using **swift 2.3** version.

```
let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if (error == nil) {
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
    completionBlock(succeeded: true, image: image)
  }
  else {
    completionBlock(succeeded: false, image: UIImage(named: "user_icon")!)
  }
})
```

Now i have converted the code to **Swift 3** and the new code is given below. The below code is not calling the completion handler. Can anyone help me with this? Here is the swift 3 code.

```
let sessionTask = URLSession.shared
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
sessionTask.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
  if (error == nil) {
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
    completionBlock(true, image)
  }
  else {
    completionBlock(false, UIImage(named: "user_icon")!)
  }
})
```

Comment: you need to execute the task calling resume method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not starting the task.

Store your task in a variable...

```
let task = session.dataTask(...
```

... and then start the task:

```
task.resume() //yes, it's always called "resume". Even if the task wasn't started yet
```